# Deploy to different environments using Eclipse

Tags: deployment, ide, eclipse

I am new to deploying from one org to another, Can someone refer some good documentation on how to deploy using Eclipse.

Also, any steps / pointers would be great..

Comment: do you mean you wan to deploy to sandbox and than copy to production? or deploy to both? you can't copy from one org to another, you need to deploy to both

Comment: Saariko, I want to deploy from sandox to production. So I was looking for options to deploy, best practices..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This page describes how to deploy with Eclipse or the Force.com IDE:
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Deploy_Force.com_Applications_Faster

And this page describes the development life cycle:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dev_lifecycle/salesforce_development_lifecycle.pdf

Another resource if you want to deploy metadata via the Force.com Migration Tool:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/index.htm

Comment: is there an updated link for this : http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Deploy_Force.com_Applications_Faster  ?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above a not well known feature is, that in a eclipse project you can select  multiple files using CTRL, then right click on one of the selected resources and select "Force.com/Deploy to server..." in the context menu. That way you will deploy the subselection only, and will not be bothered with a huge list of classes/pages/etc that you have to search for the right files.

hth

Comment: On a Macintosh the key to use is 'Command ⌘' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Roshan,

Please checkout following links. They may be helpful for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577346/salesforce-how-to-deploy-between-environments-sandboxes-live-etc

http://gokubi.com/archives/tips-for-working-with-forcecom-ide

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is MavensMate-Atom
https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-Atom

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What makes MavensMate great?

Answer (score -1):

I cannot tell of any step-by-step user's guide on the subject. But I will recommend to read carefully the Salesforce documentation like:

- [Force.com IDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) in the technical library, at the end of the page there are links that lead you to forums and Frequently Asked Questions that might help.
- Other good place is the Metadata API Developer Guide. You need to understand what you can do with the Metadata API (at the end the IDE plugin use it).
- Last but not least, be sure to follow the guidelines in Development Lifecycle Guide / Deploying to Production.

I created a tool deployPKG that simplifies the work using the Metadata API. Check out this post : [Deploy to Production in 4 Steps](https://www.deploypkg.com/deploying4steps/)