# is there a way to copy custom objects field in salesforce?

Tags: custom-object, object

UPDATE:
I'm planning to copy the custom object fields from the MANAGED package, not sure how much it impact or no impact.

I wonder if there is a way to copy a custom (object) field of the ORG A onto a custom field on my ORG B. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use developer tools like Eclipse Force.com IDE and deploy fields from Org A to Org B.

You can try out following resources:

- [Deploy Force.com Applications](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Deploy_Force.com_Applications_Faster)
- [Deploy to different environments using Eclipse (StackExchange question)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/645/deploy-to-different-environments-using-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

If you use [MavensMate](http://mavensmate.com/), you can just copy and paste the metadata for the field(s) into the source custom object and click save and it will be there for you...

The one caution I would mention is that you do then have to configure the FLS for that field..

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm planning to copy the fields from the managed package, not sure how much it impact or no impact

Comment: You might need to look out for namespaces depending on whether the source org is the packaging org

Comment: it s managed package org with namespaces on it.

Comment: If the field you are selecting in the source org is created in that org, then you can just paste it into the target org, and it will work fine. But if the field in question is part of a different package installed in the source org, then you would need to remove the namespace prefix (though in that case, you would in theory just install the package into the target org)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the free app called Config Workbook, it allows you to download the metadata for one object and and you can then just create all of those fields in a different object by uploading that same metadata file (in excel), effectively copying the fields from one object to another. Here is the appExchange link:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000q4evEAA&tab=r

After wrestling with the ANT migration tool I figured there has to be a better way, and this app was the answer I found.